# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access for Liveagent -Snap In

Tags: force.com-sites, liveagent

I am trying to implement the SnapIn part for the Liveagent console so that, I can provide chat option on my website to chat with agents using the console.

For now, it's a public force.com site on salesforce

Yesterday when I added the https://*.force.com to CORS whitelisting, It seemed to be working differently as it shows no error but, keeps on saying network issue and cannot chat with you. Please check the screenshot for this scenario.

When I checked today, I am getting this error again -- "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://wavetester-developer-edition.ap4.force.com//embeddedService/liveAgentSidebarApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wavetester-developer-edition.ap4.force.com' is therefore not allowed access. "

why is this happening? As I have put possible domains under whitelisting already! 
The whitelisted domains.
http://*.force.com
http://wavetester-developer-edition.ap4.force.com
https:// *.force.com
https:// *.salesforce.com
https:// *.salesforceliveagent.com
https:// *.sfdcstatic.com

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Yesterday , It shows different Error]

Comment: Could you try updating https:// in http://wavetester-developer-edition.ap4.force.com

Comment: Hi @Adi I didn't quite get you ? 
I have some extra info, it shows chat initiated , chat disconnected and Chat req failed in browser inspector.
I have tried seeing fiddler logs but , no use .

Comment: Hi Team , 

Thanks ! 

Actually resolved the issue. It was due to the collision of the Prechar form of the Live agent with the snap-ins. I had to disable/remove the prechat form usage for the live agent to get this work.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://cdn.rawgit.com' is therefore not allowed access. I am getting this error.